# PHP, when user is loging out intermittent page is displayed, how to remove it

Tags: php, session, logout

I was searching for a specific topic but I found nothing that I was looking for.
I'm using a php code for logout the user:

```
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
        { 
            session_start(); 
        } 
        session_unset();
        unset($_SESSION["id"]);
        unset($_SESSION["sign"]);
        unset($_SESSION["lang"]);
        unset($_SESSION["usertype"]);
        session_destroy();
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=./index.php?lang=en">';
    ?>
```

And all is working fine except one annoying thing that I would like to avoid. When user presses a log-out button it can be observed that before initial page is shown the additional blank page appears for a while... Can this behaviour be eliminated? - I don't want to show anything in the meantime, I want to just redirect the user to a home page.

Comment: Don't use meta refresh, just use a header redirect. `header('Location: ./index.php?lang=en');`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line:

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=./index.php?lang=en">';
```

With the following function call , and of course, provide your url parameters in order to perform only the php redirect inestead of triying to refresh the page.

```
Redirect("index.php");

function Redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `unset()` all variable just use `session_unset()` & `session_destroy()` for unsetting and destroying all session variables then use header to redirect to home page

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: http://yourwebsite.com');
```